# Image comparison with the reference image (Pixel base comparison)

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing

Mark assets area (based on pixels) and do the image analytics with the reference image and find missing assets.

(Pixel base comparison)

This is only to deduct missing asset (like missing ups, intercom, notebook)

- I kept a master image consider as a template with all the assets
- Whenever changes happen like replacing, missing marked items - need to mark the missing items in red color and need to alert the administrator.

I have a python code to do the image comparison but unable to customize as per my requirement.

```html
###################
# ImageCompare.py #
###################

# This module contains methods to quickly and
# easily compare two images to see how different
# they are.  This was created to be used as
# something of a motion detector.  The idea was
# That a videoconference is working if the image
# being shown changes noticeably.

# Detecting whether an image has changed was
# implemented in two ways:  Using a Histogram
# comparison (HistoCompare) and doing a pixel-
# by-pixel comparison.  It was generally found
# that the histograms of two different images
# are generally more different than a pixel-by-
# pixel comparison, but the difference is small.

import Image

# Easily the most important feature of this module
# is the fact that it requires the Python Imaging
# Library (PIL) in order to be used.  The PIL can
# be found at:
# http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/index.htm

################
# HistoCompare #
################

# HistoCompare takes in two histograms (generated
# using PIL) as well as an optional string and
# an optional double.  the histograms are those
# of the images that you want to compare.
# If you pass in "pct" as the mode, HistoCompare
# will return the percentage difference between
# the histograms (out of the total value of the
# most valuable histogram).
# If any other string is passed in as the mode,
# then HistoCompare will return True if the
# percentage difference is less than alpha, and
# False otherwise

def HistoCompare(im1, im2, mode = "pct", alpha = .01):
    if im1.size == im2.size and im1.mode == im2.mode:
        h1 = im1.histogram()
        h2 = im2.histogram()
        SumIm1 = 0.0
        SumIm2 = 0.0
 diff = 0.0
 for i in range(len(h1)):
            SumIm1 += h1[i]
            SumIm2 += h2[i]
     diff += abs(h1[i] - h2[i])
 maxSum = max(SumIm1, SumIm2)
 if mode == "pct":
            return diff/(2*maxSum)
 if diff > alpha*maxSum:
            return False
 return True
    return False

################
# PixelCompare #
################

# PixelCompare takes in two single band images
# (generated using PIL) as well as an optional
# string and an optional double.
# If you pass in "pct" as the mode, PixelCompare
# will return the percentage difference between
# the images (out of the total value of the
# most valuable histogram).
# If any other string is passed in as the mode,
# then PixelCompare will return True if the
# percentage difference is less than alpha, and
# False otherwise

def PixelCompare(im1, im2, mode = "pct", alpha = .01):
    if im1.size == im2.size and im1.mode == im2.mode:
        randPix = im1.getpixel((0,0))
        maxSum = []
        diff = []
        for channel in range(len(randPix)):
            diff += [0.0]
            maxSum += [0.0]
        width = im1.size[0]
        height = im1.size[1]
        for i in range(width):
            for j in range(height):
                pixel1 = im1.getpixel((i,j))
                pixel2 = im2.getpixel((i,j))
                for channel in range(len(randPix)):
                    maxSum[channel] += 255
                    diff[channel] += abs(pixel1[channel] - pixel2[channel])
        if mode == "pct":
            ret = ()
            for channel in range(len(randPix)):
                ret += (diff[channel]/maxSum[channel],)
            return ret
        for channel in range(len(randPix)):
            if diff[channel] > alpha*maxSum[channel]:
                return False
        return True
    return False

def XORCompare(im1, im2, mode="pct", alpha=.01):
    if im1.size == im2.size and im1.mode == im2.mode:
        XORCount = []
        randPix = im1.getpixel((0,0))
        for channel in range(len(randPix)):
            XORCount += [0.0]
        width = im1.size[0]
        height = im1.size[1]
        imXOR = ImageXOR(im1, im2)
        maxSum = 0.0
        for i in range(width):
            for j in range(height):
                pixel = imXOR.getpixel((i,j))
                for channel in range(len(pixel)):
                    XORCount[channel] += pixel[channel]
                maxSum += 255
        if mode == "pct":
            ret = ()
            for channel in range(len(randPix)):
                ret += (XORCount[channel]/maxSum,)
            return ret
        for channel in range(len(randPix)):
            if XORCount[channel] > alpha*maxSum:
                return False
        return True
    return False

def ImageCompare(im1, im2, mode = "pct", alpha = .01):
    if im1.size == im2.size and im1.mode == im2.mode:
        HistComp = HistoCompare(im1, im2, "pct")
        PixComp = PixelCompare(im1, im2, "pct")
        XORComp = XORCompare(im1, im2, "pct")
        if mode == "pct":
            return (HistComp, PixComp, XORComp)
        if mode == "alpha":
            if HistComp > alpha:
                return False
            for pct in PixComp:
                if pct > alpha:
                    return False
            for pct in XORComp:
                if pct > alpha:
                    return False
            return True
    return False

def FindDifferences(im1, im2):
    if im1.size == im2.size and im1.mode == im2.mode:
        width = im1.size[0]
        height = im2.size[1]
        ret = Image.new(im1.mode, im1.size)
        for i in range(width):
            for j in range(height):
                pixel1 = im1.getpixel((i,j))
                pixel2 = im2.getpixel((i,j))
                putPix = ()
                for channel in range(len(pixel1)):
                    putPix += (abs(pixel1[channel] - pixel2[channel]),)
                ret.putpixel((i,j), putPix)
        return ret
    return False

def ImageXOR(im1, im2):
    if im1.size == im2.size and im1.mode == im2.mode:
        width = im1.size[0]
        height = im2.size[1]
        ret = Image.new(im1.mode, im1.size)
        for i in range(width):
            for j in range(height):
                pixel1 = im1.getpixel((i,j))
                pixel2 = im2.getpixel((i,j))
                putPix = ()
                for channel in range(len(pixel1)):
                    putPix += (pixel1[channel]^pixel2[channel],)
                ret.putpixel((i,j), putPix)
        return ret
    return False

def GetKey(size, mode, seed = 0):
    import random
    key = Image.new(mode, size)
    random.seed(seed)
    for i in range(size[0]):
        for j in range(size[1]):
            if mode == "RGB":
                key.putpixel((i,j), (random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255)))
            if mode == "CMYK":
                key.putpixel((i,j), (random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255), random.randint(-128,127)))
            if mode == "L":
                key.putpixel((i,j), random.randint(0,255))
    return key

def MonitorPicture(file, method="all", tolerance=.01):
    image = Image.open(file)
    image2 = image
    while True:
        if method == "all":
            if ImageCompare(image, image2, "alpha", tolerance) == False:
                return "BING!"
        elif method == "Histogram" or method == "hist":
            if HistoCompare(image, image2, "alpha", tolerance) == False:
                return "BING!"
        elif method == "Pixel-by-pixel" or method == "pix":
            if PixelCompare(image, image2, "alpha", tolerance) == False:
                return "BING!"
        elif method == "XOR" or method == "xor":
            if XORCompare(image, image2, "alpha", tolerance) == False:
                return "BING!"
        else:
            return False, "Please enter a valid method: all, hist, pix or xor"
        image2 = image
        image = Image.open(file)

def EncryptImage(file, seed=0):
    image = Image.open(file)
    key = GetKey(image.size, image.mode, seed)
    enc = ImageXOR(image, key)
    enc.save(file)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Could you describe the problem you're having, and strip down your code to the minimum necessary to reproduce it.

Comment: I have remote location camera
- I need to track my assets (Like generators, UPS, batteries)
- Live streaming is very difficult due to the bandwidth limitation
- can able to get latest images by ftp
- Need to do programmatically checking for image comparison for assets tracking.

Comment: how consistent is the lighting? are you doing computation on-site and only sending update if deemed necessary? If this is someone else's code you're looking to adapt, you should credit them somewhere..

Comment: - it is remote tower so, power issue will be very limited. Based on alarm setting, getting updated.  Yes need to do the changes accordingly.

Comment: unless the images are super high resolution or you're trying to do high frame rate, this doesn't seem like an application that would require too much performance. (could likely be done on a raspberry pi)

Comment: - Low resolution and frame 4 for 1 sec
- Since limited bandwidth

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139504/discussion-between-aaron-and-bcrajkumar).